# ASP.NET Web Api 2.0 with Entity framework throws exception when hosted as Web site

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I am using ASP.NET web api 2.0 with EF 6.0. I deploye my application using VS publish feature. when i locally host my application in IIS as Web site and access the API get method it thorws exception which is

```
<ExceptionMessage>
The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.ObjectDisposedException</ExceptionType>
```

It works fine when i host my application as Web application in Default application or change my web site application pool to Default application.

Comment: What does look like the executed code ? (controller method being hit)